# Using .fadeout('slow') for CSS display function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this little piece of JavaScript code:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

I am trying to add a fadeout effect for when the targeted ID is set to `style.display = 'none';` but I cannot figure out how. I know that I must use `.fadeOut('slow')` but I don't know how and where exactly to insert that part.

Comment: Do you even use jQuery?  If yes this might help you: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: Note that in your script you are using *plain* JavaScript, i.e. without any libraries. `.fadeOut()` is part of jQuery, a library built on top of JavaScript. This means that to use fadeOut and other jQuery functions, you first need to load jQuery in your document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Jquery it could be really simple

http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    $( "#"+id).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
}
```

Comment: Wow! That simple? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 function toggle_visibility(id) {
   // since you are using jQuery you don't need to use `getElementById`.
   $('#'.id).fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using jQuery's [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) function. You can also input milliseconds instead of "slow" or "fast". If you want half a second you could input `500` for example.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
   $('h1').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<h1>Click the button and I'll be gone :(</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [jQuery.Hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

- show: $('#id').show( "slow")
- hide: $('#id').hide( "slow")